# How can I extract specific JSON elements with PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

I'm toying with a small program that can pass a list of words to the Merriam-Webster API, and gets returned the definition, part of speech, sample sentence and so on.

The JSON string returned for each word by the API is as follows:

```
    {
        "meta": {
            "id": "vase",
            "uuid": "eb4f8388-84b2-4fd4-bfc8-2686a0222b73",
            "src": "learners",
            "section": "alpha",
            "target": {
                "tuuid": "60e7797e-fd75-43e1-a941-3def0963d822",
                "tsrc": "collegiate"
            },
            "stems": [
                "vase",
                "vaselike",
                "vases"
            ],
            "app-shortdef": {
                "hw": "vase",
                "fl": "noun",
                "def": ["{bc} a container that is used for holding flowers or for decoration"]
            },
            "offensive": false
        },
        "hwi": {
            "hw": "vase",
            "prs": [
                {
                    "ipa": "ˈveɪs",
                    "pun": ",",
                    "sound": {"audio": "vase0002"}
                },
                {
                    "l": "British",
                    "ipa": "ˈvɑːz",
                    "sound": {"audio": "vase0003"}
                }
            ]
        },
        "fl": "noun",
        "ins": [
            {
                "il": "plural",
                "if": "vas*es"
            }
        ],
        "gram": "count",
        "def": [
            {
                "sseq": [
                    [
                        [
                            "sense",
                            {
                                "dt": [
                                    [
                                        "text",
                                        "{bc}a container that is used for holding flowers or for decoration "
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        "vis",
                                        [
                                            {"t": "a beautiful Chinese {it}vase{/it}"},
                                            {"t": "a {it}vase{/it} of roses"}
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        "shortdef": ["a container that is used for holding flowers or for decoration"]
    }
]
```

The code I'm using to pull the information from the API is as follows:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
        // process the line read.
        //$json_new = grab_json_definition(trim($line), "collegiate", "0f3ee238-c219-472d-9079-df5ec8c0eb7d");
        $json_new = grab_json_definition(trim($line) , "learners", "d300a82d-1f00-4f09-ac62-7ab37be796e8");

        $data = json_decode($json_new, true);

        echo "Word: " . $data[0]['meta']['id'] . "<br/>";
        echo "IPA: " . $data[0]['hwi']['prs'][0][ipa] . "<br/>";
        echo "Part of Speech: " . $data[0]['fl'] . "<br/>";

        echo "Definition: " . $data[0]['shortdef'][0] . "<br/>";
        echo "Sentence: " . $data[0]['def'][0]['sseq'][0][0][0] . "<br/>";

    }

    fclose($handle);
}
else
{
    // error opening the file.
    
}



function grab_json_definition($word, $ref, $key)
{
    $uri = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/" . urlencode($ref) . "/json/" . urlencode($word) . "?key=" . urlencode($key);

    return file_get_contents($uri);

};

?>
```

I can easily navigate through to get the Word, Definition and so on, but I can't navigate down to "t" to get the sample sentences. I'm sure it's something basic but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it its an array (wrapped in `[]`) loop it, if not then directly access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JSON example is broken, I believe it is missing a `[` in the beginning.

Now, Here is an example, where I load the contents of the file, `json_decode` your SINGLE example. Note that I am not adding a `foreach loop` or `while loop`, but I am getting all of the attributes you are aiming for:

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents('inputfile.txt');
$data = json_decode($f);
print_r($data);

    echo "Word: " . $data[0]->meta->id . "<br/>";
    echo "IPA: " . $data[0]->hwi->prs[0]->ipa . "<br/>";
    echo "Part of Speech: " . $data[0]->fl . "<br/>";

    echo "Definition: " . $data[0]->shortdef[0] . "<br/>";
    echo "Sentence: " . $data[0]->def[0]->sseq[0][0][0] . "<br/>";
    echo "T1: " . $data[0]->def[0]->sseq[0][0][1]->dt[1][1][0]->t . "<br/>"; // those can also be in foreach loop, I am just showing the basic example of accessing the attributes
    echo "T2: " . $data[0]->def[0]->sseq[0][0][1]->dt[1][1][1]->t . "<br/>";
```

You can extend this code, or modify yours to add while/foreach loops... as you need them..

Comment: JSON is indeed broken - cut and paste error.

Thank you very much for the clear explanation - it gives me plenty to work with.